# Not displaying after quote mark

Tags: javascript, jquery

After I run my script, the input field essentially looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="How do you " />
```

Even if I slash the quotes or change them to `&quot;` it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

```
$('input').html(function() {
    var dataVal = 'How do you "feel" about that?';

    return '<input type="text" value="' + dataVal + '" />';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after the `dataVal` definition.

```
dataVal = dataVal.replace(/"/g,"&quot;")
```

It replaces all `"` characters by the HTML entity of a quotation mark, fixing your code.

Currently, your parsed HTML looks like this:
`<input type="text" value="How do you "feel" about that?" />`, which is translated to
`<input type="text" value="How do you " />`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want this instead:

```
$('input').val(function() {
    var dataVal = 'How do you "feel" about that?';
    return dataVal;
});
```

or just

```
$('input').val('How do you "feel" about that?');
```

`html` is for defining the contained html of an element, whereas `val` is for defining the value of an input field.

Comment: There is more going on but I stripped out some code to make it simpler to troubleshoot.

Thanks for your help.